# Snap SVG animation rotate

Tags: html, css, svg, snap.svg

I am working on a SVG animation for the first time, and have bumped into an issue :

I have an arrow (made in illustrator) following a path, I used a function found on the famous codepen animaton path that I used.
Now, I managed to get the angle of the arrow right (after multiple tries), but what happens now is that at the end of my animation, for a reason I can't undersand, the arrow just does a weird rotate (like it was putting itself back into its original position).

Here is a JSFiddle of my problem :

http://jsfiddle.net/4cvaM/3/

This is the line where I believe the problem is at, although I don't quite understand what the .alpha + 90 really does

```
tipGroup.transform( 't' + parseInt(movePoint.x - 8) + ',' + parseInt( movePoint.y - 9) + 'r' + (movePoint.alpha + 90));
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Quick fix is just set the end to be length - 1, http://jsfiddle.net/4cvaM/8/

Answer (score 0):

Judging from this commented line of code in the Snap lib about the angle derivative :

https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/src/path.js#L169

And these various discussion about the problem you encounter on the mailing lists :

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/snapsvg/TOYtCQvLNHA/w8JCg5BVQMgJ
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/raphaeljs/W9bA0SkArVY/ktkbu2OndAIJ

My guess is that it's a library bug, and you should seek help through the github issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the links @Delapouite.

I got my answer on the google forums, I believe you are right and it might be a lirary bug, but if anyone comes by, here's a quick fix :

You have to add -1 to your path length in the animate function, this prevents it going to the end thus not rotating the triangle.
I guess it's a hack and it still annoys me, but at least it works !

The code that I changed is at line 46 on the fiddle :

```
Snap.animate(0, arrowLenght-1, function( value )
```

And the updated fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/4cvaM/9/